# Insufficient permissions exception from BigQuery API

Tags: f#, google-bigquery

I am getting an "Insufficient Permissions" exception from BigQuery when trying to list the datasets in my project (via service.Datasets.List). What do I have to do to grant this permission? Full F# source code:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Threading

open Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
open Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2
open Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data
open Google.Apis.Services

let private service =
    let credential =
        let secrets =
            use stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets
        let task =
            GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                secrets,
                [| BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery |],
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None)
        printfn "Authenticating"
        task
            |> Async.AwaitTask
            |> Async.RunSynchronously
    let initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer(HttpClientInitializer = credential)
    new BigqueryService(initializer)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let projectId = "{MyProjectId}"
    let list = service.Datasets.List(projectId).Execute()
    for dataset in list.Datasets do
        printfn "%A" dataset.FriendlyName
    0
```

Comment: Very excited to see a bigquery user coding in F#. "Insufficient Permissions" likely means that your request is getting rejected very early in the request (before it gets to the bigquery backend). It is possible your project doesn't have bigquery enabled. Is there any more information provided with the error?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that I was missing a key line of boilerplate code:

```
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder <- "Tasks.Auth.Store";
```

I don't really understand what this does (the documentation is woefully sparse), but adding this line solved the problem.